# The function that downloads continously

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests

I need help or suggestions.

I am POST-ing orders that will be ready after N - amounts of time. So after posting the request I am checking the status of the order with the `while` loop. I want to download orders as soon as they are ready. In one time I can download 5 orders in parallel, because of the endpoint limit.

Currently, my idea is based on the storing the links of the ready orders and wait untill the all orders ready and then start downloading orders with `Threading` module. It is working fine, unfortunately the links to download have expire date, which means that if I have a lot of orders I will not have sufficient time to download.

So, i am looking for new solution. The new idea is based on the `first come first serve`, which means I should have a function that always checks the list and if there is a link it will start download. But in one time I should have only 5 active downloadings. Whenever there is space for the new link, it should be started downloading. `Threading` is waiting for all threads to be finished to start download the next batch.

I know there a lot of txt, but I am not sure which libraries I should explore. Can I get some directions or better ideas to handle this challenge. The core idea should be "there should be 5 active downloadings always untill orders downloaded"

Comment: Using `threading` is probably a good way to manage concurrency when you are doing non-python-intensive (e.g. blocking / IO intensive) work.

Comment: If you have a rough skeleton of your program people would probably give you more advice.